# How to redirect Magento 2 Website to open through www.?

Tags: magento-2.1

My Magento 2 website is not displaying .when using www.  before the domain name. any solution for this .?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should open the .htaccess file in the Magento folder. In it locate the "RewriteEngine on" line and right after it add the following lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Once you do this, save the .htaccess file and log in to the administrative end of Magento.

Then go to the **Stores > Configuration > General** and from the left panel click the `"Web"` button.

Unfold the **"Base URLs (Secure)"** set of options and change the **"Secure Base URL"** option from http://yourdomain.com to http://www.yourdomain.com.

Save the changes and your Magento website will be running with www.yourdomain.com only!

Comment: Thank you.! but this is not working .with me after edit .httpaccess  .unable to access web admin panel.

Comment: Please check with proper .htaccess configurations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138510/redirect-non-www-to-www-on-magento